# Videojs Vast Play Button

Tags: javascript, video.js

we have a problem with the play button (videojs + videojs vast plugin). 
If no commercial is playing, the big play button has no function, only the little play button. Is there a workaround that the big play button is working.

Example

```
// init first player
videojs('vid_673732', {
    "controls": true,
        "autoplay": true,
        "preload": "auto"
}, function () {
    var videoPlayer = this;
    videoPlayer.muted(false);
    videoPlayer.ads();
    videoPlayer.vast({
        url: "http://ad3.adfarm1.adition.com/banner?sid=3108095&wpt=X",
        skip: "-1"
    }); // VAST link always delivering a test ad
    videoPlayer.ga();
    videoPlayer.on("loadedmetadata", function () {
        videoPlayer.play();
    });
});

// init second player
videojs('vid_673662', {
    "controls": true,
        "autoplay": true,
        "preload": "auto"
}, function () {
    var videoPlayer = this;
    videoPlayer.muted(false);
    videoPlayer.ads();
    videoPlayer.vast({
        url: "http://ad3.adfarm1.adition.com/banner?sid=2721754&wpt=X",
        skip: "-1"
    }); // VAST link NOT always delivering ads
    videoPlayer.ga();
    videoPlayer.on("loadedmetadata", function () {
        videoPlayer.play();
    });
});
```

Example: [hier](http://jsfiddle.net/eho5p0ss/5/)
(Example is autoplay , not a big play button)

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  There is no big play button since you auto play. The big play button by default is only shown before playback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.

It turned out to be the videojs-ads plugin. This has since been resolved. You can find more details on their GitHub: https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/issues/64

I recommend updating the videojs ads plugin: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads